# Installing pip on an airgapped machine

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install pip on an airgapped machine following this [guide](http://chrisclaxton.blogspot.com/2017/05/python-libraries-on-air-gapped-machine.html), however I've encountered the following error:

```
~$ python3 pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip install --no-index pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/api/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Tried installing pip via source distribution (pip-23.0.1.tar.gz) using setup.py but also encountered issues with that method.

Comment: You can also install pip through your system's package manager. For example, for Ubuntu Kinetic, you can download the .deb [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/python3-pip).

Comment: You might need to install `python3-distutils` to fix this error, see https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/issues/124

Comment: What about `path/to/pythonX.Y -m ensurepip`?